# In Rails 5, how do I make Rails save all my attributes in an object defined in a seed file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, updates, ruby-on-rails-5, seed

**Edit:**

Gave the alternate solution a go, but using this data

```
crawlers = []
crawler1 = WebCrawler.new({ 
  class_name: "MyObjectService",
  start_url: "stuff?format=json&key=88b3284d4b892b430767b830d0c0eb51", 
  begin_with_start_url: false, 
  active: true
})
crawlers.push(crawler1)
```

The call to rake db:seed failed with the below message.  Evidently even though the row already exists, Rails is attempting to update its id column with a null value.

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, MyObjectService, null, null, stuff/500?format=json&key=88b3284d4b892..., null, f, t, null, null, null, 1).
: UPDATE "web_crawlers" SET "id" = $1, "start_time" = $2, "end_time" = $3, "active" = $4, "created_at" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "web_crawlers"."id" = $7
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `async_exec'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:598:in `block in exec_no_cache'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:589:in `block in log'
```

Comment: find_or_create_by() helps u finds the first record with the given attributes, or creates a record with the attributes if one is not found. Now the error occurs because it cannot find the specified class name (c.class_name) and try to create new one by passing only the class_name, while other field is non-null column and causing the error...if me, I will try to find, if find then update it, else create it. find_or_create_by is somehow misused in this case.

Comment: Hi, I'm not understanding your comment.  The record dosen't exist by class name, so it should be created but it is not being created with all the information I supplied.  How do I get it to?

Comment: In my alternative solution, you don't assign the crawlers to objects right away, they are hashes. Not sure if you did that, but it's not reflected in your updated question. Please let me know if you gave that a try!

Comment: Oh, I must have misunderstood.  But then this line -- "crawlers.each do |c|" in your alternate solution implies that crawlers is an array (which was how I originally had it).  YOu're saying that "crawlers" is a hash?

Comment: My understanding is that you have many declarations of crawler objects as seed info. Instead of initializing them with a `.new`, I've just made them into hashes, then they are all pushed into an array, like you originally had it. Then they are looped through and either update or create the DB objects as necessary. I'll edit my answer to make this more explicit.

Comment: Ok so your alternate solution also requires altering the code in every place where a crawler declaration is made -- by changing it from .new to a hash is that right?

Comment: @Dave -- I rewrote my answer to allow you to not update the code in many places. Give it a try and let me know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

This approach does not require the code to be updated in many places. We use `.attributes` to get set of attributes assigned in the `.new` call. Then we check to find a `WebCrawler` instance that has the `class_name` of each crawler instance defined. From there we update or create.

```
crawlers = []

crawler7 = WebCrawler.new({
  class_name: "MainService",
  start_url: "...",
  ...
})

crawlers.push(crawler7)

crawlers.each do |c|
  web_crawler = WebCrawler.find_by(class_name: c.attributes['class_name'])

  if web_crawler
    web_crawler.update(c.attributes)
  else
    c.save
  end
end
```

[Here's a link to the docs.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) See the first sentence under the header: "Finds the first record with the given attributes, or creates a record with the attributes if one is not found." Since the given attribute is only the name, it violates your validations.

Comment: Sadly, got the error, "PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint" when I tried to run this.  I don't specify an id in my object definitions, so maybe that's why its getting confused?

Comment: Nvm, everything works if I change the line to "web_crawler.update(c.attributes.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at"))"

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [`find_or_create_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by):

> Finds the first record with the given attributes, or creates a record with the attributes if one is not found

Since you only passed the `class_name` attribute to `find_or_create_by`, the record created does not have the other attributes set. (Note that `new` or `initialize` only initialize a Ruby object in memory, only methods like `update`, `save` or `create` actually write a record to the database.)

Rather than calling `WebCrawler.new` and then passing attributes from these objects to a separate `find_or_create_by` call, a simpler approach would be to call the finder method from the start, updating the newly-created or existing record with the additional parameters:

```
...
crawler7 = WebCrawler.find_or_initialize_by( 
  class_name: "MainService"
).update!(
  start_url: "...", 
  ...
)
#  Done- the record is created/updated in the database
```

Notes:

1. I'd recommend [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by) instead of `find_or_create_by` here to skip an extra database query, since the  `update` afterwards will save the record to the database in the next step anyway.
2. I'd recommend [`update!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21) instead of [`update`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) to raise an exception (rather than fail silently without saving) if validation fails.

#### Alternate approach

If minimal effort changing existing code is important, you can use an alternate approach much closer to your original:

```
...
crawler7 = WebCrawler.new({ 
  class_name: "MainService",
  start_url: "...", 
  ...
})
crawlers.push(crawler7)
#  

# Create the crawlers 
crawlers.each do |c|
  crawler = WebCrawler.find_or_initialize_by(class_name: c.class_name)
  crawler.update!(c.attributes)
end
```

This approach is less simple (because it iterates through all objects twice) and less efficient (because it initializes 2 Ruby objects per record), but it should still get the job done.

Comment: So I understand your solution properly, you're sayhing instead of  changing code in one place, I must chagen it everything I declare a "crawler" object?  So if I declare 50 objects, I need to update my code in 50 places, is that right?

Comment: @Dave yes, to implement the solution I've described you'll need to change your existing code. If minimal effort to change your code is important, you can use an alternate approach (see edit).

Answer (score 1):

Model#new only instantiates an object but does not persist it in the database, you'd still need to call Model#save on the instance.

Model#create creates it immediately, assuming it passes validations, in the db. This should fix the null issue you're having in your error message. Essentially you're trying to update an object that hasn't been persisted yet. You can check this via the persisted? method.